# How to properly declare type for React wrapper component (HOC) using Typescript

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm trying to implement a simple HOC for enhancing components with custom tooltips. Although the code works fine I cannot figure out how to properly declare types.
A simplified version of my HOC looks like this:

```
const withTooltip = <P extends {}>(
  BaseComponent: React.ComponentType<P>
): React.FC<P & { title?: string }> => ({ title, ...rest }) => {
  
  return (
    <>
      <BaseComponent {...rest} />
      <Tooltip title={title}/>
    </>
  );
};
```

But I'm getting a Typescript error:

```
Type 'Omit<PropsWithChildren<P & { title?: string | undefined; }>, "title">' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & P & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
  Type 'Omit<PropsWithChildren<P & { title?: string | undefined; }>, "title">' is not assignable to type 'P'.
    'Omit<PropsWithChildren<P & { title?: string | undefined; }>, "title">' is assignable to the constraint of type 'P', but 'P' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint '{}'.
```

How can I properly declare types for such a HOC?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the type of infered `rest` props:

```js
import React, { ComponentType } from 'react'

const Tooltip = (props: { title?: string }) => null

type OptionalTitle = { title?: string };

const withTooltip = <P extends object = object>(
  BaseComponent: ComponentType<Omit<P & OptionalTitle, "title">>
): React.FC<P & OptionalTitle> => ({ title, ...rest }) => {

  return (
    <>
      <BaseComponent {...rest} />
      <Tooltip title={title} />
    </>
  );
};
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution doesn't work

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTACoCeYScAvnAGZRFwDkUqGHAUHzSkAzvEoQIAGxjAwcALxwAFGDZhhALlxwZMSUgD8W0VGAkA5owCUCgHxwSAV0mSBMWvQDyYGaRSTKYD16RTxdfSM4EzNLBgBuASESUTgAdyCAC3EpGTlFAB4ABTgkAA8YcgATYTgIACMAKyQMBVrG5phbJT44OAAhFGEkQmIyCi0RyDGqD3zPECCiuAAyOG9fEn9A4OwAInCkXdtbPistZHQYADoAMXwl1fXgPwCg-Xt5eyUwt6RsK4B3BSDBsn1wAl63BgjigJGUPV6cHyJ0RiPyAyGk1I5HgOABVyBMCYAHoUaikdlpLIdL95DgDiSyb18qSEVYEvEgA

Comment: Please check the link, I dont have any errors

Comment: Sorry for not being more specific. Yes, this solution doesn't cause errors. But when I try to use this HOC in the app it seems that Typescript infers type for the wrapped component to simple `React.FC<OptionalTitle>` and I need to explicitly show the right type like: `withTooltip<ComponentProps<typeof SomeComponent>>(SomeComponent)`

Comment: COuld you please provide en example in toyr answer. Will be much easier for me

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAJQKYEMDGMA0cDecDCE4EAdkiTACoCeYScAvnAGZRFwDkUqGHAUHzSkAzvEoQIAGxjAwcALxwAFGDZhhALlxwZMSUgD8W0VGAkA5owCUCgHxwSAV0mSBMWvQDyYGaRSTKYD16RTxdfSM4EzNLBgBuASESUTgAdyCAC3EpGTlFAB4ABTgkAA8YcgATYTgIACMAKyQMBVrG5phbJT44OAAhFGEkQmIyCi0RyDGqD3zPECCiuAAyOG9fEn9A4OwAInCkXdtbPistZHQYADoAMXwl1fXgPwCg-Xt5eyUwt6RsK4B3BSDBsn1wAl63BgjigJGUPV6cHyJ0RiPyAyGk1I5HgOABVyBMCYAHoUaikdlpLIdL95DgDiSyb18qSEVYEvEBGYKlBmOh6JQkKJCmoajgEcIiEgRRAwFonCA6kgoHwGIkRGIhTAsdNzjxrnd8oLhaKPsocJKQNK1CC7ODIUhobD4aj8pVgAA3JmIi1SmVgNWu4nur1s1Xq5Ka0QAdUylNyrXSMCyEipYCNWv9wi6xu1RCmOPZQA

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/235125/discussion-between-captain-yossarian-and-max).